# Point doesn't show in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw a point using OpenGL like below, but it only displays a black window. Can someone tell me what's the error?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0,0,1.0);
    glPointSize(10);
    //glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D (0.0,0.0,400, 150);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float pointSize = 5;
    glPointSize(10);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); // render with points
    glVertex2i(50,40); //display a point
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w,int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)w,(GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0,(GLdouble)w,0.0,(GLdouble)h,-1.0,1.0);
}

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("Draw Simple Object");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you're passing to `gluOrtho2d` look wrong. The order is left, right, top, bottom. You've set both the left and right to 0.0. Based on your `glutInitWindowSize` call, I'd guess what you want is something like `gluOrtho2d(0.0, 400.0, 0.0, 150.0);` (or maybe `gluOrtho2d(0.0, 400.0, 150.0, 0.0);`) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It took me a lot time to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the points you draw are black and the background is, too?
Have you tried adding this line to the beginning of your display function:

glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);